# Flutter: Is there a way to "snooze" the internet permission popup on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, permissions

With the latest versions of iOS, applications that use the internet now ask for permission in a pop-up window at the beginning of the app. Is there a way to avoid this behavior, and ask for internet permission on a later screen?

I'm using the latest stable version of Flutter: 3.16.9

Thanks.

[image: example]

I thought it was due to the Firebase packages I had installed, such as FirebaseAuth or CloudFirestore, but after literally uninstalling them from the project it still asks for internet permission at the start of the app.

This is my main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  try {
    await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
        debug:
            false, // optional: set to false to disable printing logs to console (default: true)
        ignoreSsl:
            false // option: set to false to disable working with http links (default: false)
        );
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    PhotoManager.clearFileCache();
  }

  return runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: Theme(
        child: TrackingWrapper(
          child: AppBlocWrapper(
            child: AppBuilder(
              builder: (context) => MaterialApp(
                navigatorKey: materialAppKey,
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  AppLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                ],
                supportedLocales: [
                  Locale('en'),
                  Locale('it'),
                ],
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                initialRoute: '/',
                onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                  switch (settings.name) {
                    ...
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```